# Android Emulator Play Store - not able to download app from Play Store

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-play, android-virtual-device

I'm using the new Android Studio 3.0 with Google Play Store.  When I open the Play Store and search for apps like Slack, I am able to download it.  However, when I search for HockeyApp by Microsoft or one of my personal apps, I am not able to download it.  At first, I think it was a uses-feature problem that the emulator didn't have I made all of them false, especially autoFocus.

Anyways, when I go to the Play Store and search for my app, I see the following message "Your device isn't compatible with this version."  I'm able to run the same app on the emulator and it is working fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you attach a Gradle file?
Have you selected the type of version of your project when you started a new project?